# Tethering Droid 2 Global with Wireless Tether after 2.3 Gingerbread update

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-droid-2, verizon, wifi-tethering

My D2G updated to 2.3 today, and I'm no longer able to tether.

Prevously, I had no problem using [Wireless Tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether) 2.0.7 with Android 2.2.

Now that I'm on 2.3:

- Wireless Tether 2.0.7 will start up and I'm able to connect my laptop to its WiFi network, but Verizon redirects me to the [self-provisioning page](https://dunsp.vzw.com/newSelfProvisioning/SelfProvisioning); I have no internet access.
- Wireless Tether 3.1-beta6 doesn't work.  It says tethering is enabled, but the WiFi network does not show up on any other devices.

How can I fix this?

---

**Edit:** This appears to be a [reported issue](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/issues/detail?id=1088).

Comment: are you running a custom rom, or just a rooted version of the stock one?

Comment: @jlehenbauer: Rooted stock.

Comment: hmm. this same kind of thing happened to mine, but it ended up being that the ROM i was using (not stock) had this functionality built in, and the wifi-tether app interfered. but obviously, this doesn't quite fit your problem. sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this, but it's not pretty.  Following the advice in [this thread](http://rootzwiki.com/showthread.php?3626), I applied a hack to the radio that gets Wireless Tether working.

---

**Edit:** I can confirm this exact procedure will also work on a Droid X.

---

1. Download and install [RadioComm](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7632904/RadioComm_v11.11.7_Install.msi).  It worked fine on Windows 7 x64.
2. Open Radiocom.  This was the first time I opened the app, and a splash screen asked for me to "select which MA to use."  I couldn't find the MA mentioned in the thread in this list, so I just selected 3G All Others (or something like that).
3. Open the *Main* menu, select *MA*, *Common*, *MDM 6x00 Chipset Base*.
4. Open the *Settings* menu, select *USB*, *PST USB Driver*.
5. Connect phone to computer via USB.  Change the phone's USB connection mode to *PC Mode*.
6. The *Radio Detection* icon on the right side of RadioComm will turn green.
7. Scroll to the *P2K 4* tab.
8. In the *STELEM / RDELEM* section, tick the *Dec Entries* radio box.
9. In the text boxes, enter:

   ```
   Element ID: 8040
   Record #:   1
   Offset:     0
   Length:     128
   ```

   Press `RDELEM`.  It will turn green and the following data should appear:

   ```
   40767A7733672E636F6D00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   ```
10. Change `Element ID` to `8041`.
11. Press `STELEM`.  It will turn green.
12. Change `Element ID` to `8091`.
13. Press `STELEM`.
14. Change the phone's USB connection mode to *Charge Only*.
15. Reboot the phone.
16. Install [Wifi Tether 3.1-beta6](http://android-wifi-tether.googlecode.com/files/wifi_tether_v3_1-beta6.apk).
17. In Wifi Tether's settings, change the Device Profile to *Motorola DroidX (CDMA)*.  (*Droid2* does **not** work.)  This is a good time to set your SSID and encryption as well.
18. Done.  You can now tether.

In case you need to revert the changes we just made, here's the original values:  (these are the same on a D2G and Droid X)

`8041`:

```
4064756E2E767A7733672E636F6D000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

`8091`:

```
40767A7733672E636F6D00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: I guess I had the WiFi Tether still running in the background so I had to do this twice. For others who already have WiFi Tether 3.1-beta6 loaded, reboot your phone first then follow josh3736's instructions. Worked great on my Verizon Droid 2 Global after the 2.3.3 OTA update.

Comment: Since the 4.5.605 update to Droid X, this seems to be doing the trick so far (10 minutes in). Thanks for the hack! josh3736 FTW

Comment: This is awesome. Worked great!

Answer (score 1):

We have here two situations colliding. For Wireless-Tether to have worked in the first place, it means that you were rooted.

It is typical behavior of OTA updates to remove root access. You must re-root your device in order to ensure that Wireless-Tether will work properly again.

The root access portion of Wireless-Tether is what helps it work its magic that prevents that Verizon hijack page from coming up.

Comment: Yes, I was rooted.  Before the update, I manually unrooted (z4root) to ensure the update went smoothly, and after the update, I re-rooted with [the Droid 3 one-click root](http://www.psouza4.com/droid3/).  I am rooted properly (Titanium Backup works).

Answer (score 0):

The Droid X has a similar issue with this, make sure that you set the device profile to Droid 2 in wifi tether.  This is a setting that was added in the Wifi tether 3.0+ versions.

Comment: Setting the device profile has no effect.